# How to translate an entire UIView and retain gesture recognition?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a `UIView` "MainView" that initially appears as follows:

[image]

The gradient bar is part of MainView, the whitespace beneath is part of a Container View subview.
When the search button in top-right is tapped, I animate a searchBar from offscreen to be visible in the view:

[image]

I manage to do this by the following code:

```
CGRect currentViewFrame = self.view.bounds;
currentViewFrame.origin.y += searchViewHeight;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                      delay:0.0
     usingSpringWithDamping:1.0
      initialSpringVelocity:4.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
                        self.view.frame = currentViewFrame;
                    }
                    completion:^(BOOL finished)
                    {
                    }];
```

Visually, the result of this animation is perfect.  The entire view shifts, and the searchBar is now on screen.  However, the searchBar does not respond to interaction.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but I expect this is because the MainView's frame no longer includes the screen area that the searchBar now occupies, so its effectively a gesture deadzone.

So this makes me think that instead of lazily animating the entire MainView down to accomodate the searchBar, I must instead individually translate all subviews of MainView one at a time.  In this simple situation, that would not be a big problem, but I can envision a circumstance with tens of subviews making that completely unrealistic.

What is the best method to accomplish what I am trying to do?  Is there a secret to animating entire views/subviews without having gesture deadzones?  Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If it's because you're messing with the mainView, why not wrap the gradientBar within another view and shift that down? I.E. -> self.main has a searchbar and self.MainView. self.MainView contains gradientBar. then with UIAnimation, you simply move self.MainView down instead of self.view

Comment: Okay I think I see what you're saying.  My MainView should have the searchBar, already on screen, but hidden behind a subview which contains the gradient bar and the container view.  Then, instead of animating the searchBar from offscreen, I just animate the subview down?  That makes a lot of sense for this situation...

Comment: However - Suppose for some reason I really did need to have the searchBar initially outside the bounds of the MainView.  Is there an answer to my question? Or is that just an impractical way of doing things?

Comment: Try to use `[searchBar becomeFirstResponer] ;`

Comment: @Morpheus, that "works" in that it allows you to type 'n such.  But user expectancy is to be able to tap to search, as well as perhaps to realign the cursor, etc; so being responsive to touch is mandatory.

Comment: Didn't understand you.

Comment: Generally I haven't run into cases where you're manipulating the bounds of self.view to be honest. I'm sure there are some reasons for doing so, but I'd say it's an impractical way of doing things at least for this specific issue